# Using python-colorama in Docker

Tags: python, docker

## Problem

I am trying to use the python module `colorama` (to print coloured messages) within Docker but unfortunately it does not work:

- Running from the terminal `python3 main.py` works as expected.
- Running `docker run -p 5000:5000 hello_docker:latest` does not ==> prints the message w/out colour.

## Project

**OS**

```
Kernel Version: 4.19.81-Re4son-v8l+
Operating System: Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
OSType: linux
Architecture: aarch64
```

**Tree**

```
./main.py
./__init__.py
./requirements.txt
./Dockerfile
```

**Dockerfile**

```
# Dockerfile
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /srv
ADD ./requirements.txt /srv/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ADD . /srv
CMD python /srv/main.py
```

**requirements.txt**

```
colorama
```

**main.py**

```py
from colorama import init, Fore, Style


if __name__ == '__main__':
    init()
    msg = Fore.GREEN + "Python 3.8 says hello in green from Docker !" + Style.RESET_ALL
    print(msg, flush=True)
```

Comment: did you get the msg like "Python 3.8 says...." or not? You can `init()` not in the `if` scope

Comment: @Faran2007 Yes I did get the message but with _default colour_. I can try with `init()` outside of the condition. However, since running `python3 main.py` works (prints in green) I doubt that this will solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could activate the `-it` flag

```sh
docker run -it -p 5000:5000 hello_docker:latest
```

-it is --interactive + --tty. This enable us to view the output straight inside of the container.

```
-t   : Allocate a pseudo-tty
-i   : Keep STDIN open even if not attached
```

- [Docker Run Documentaion](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)